# What's the regular pattern to implement `-init` chain when subclassing UIView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, design-patterns

When I make an object to use in NIB, the object should implement `-initWithCoder:`. However I can't figure out regular pattern implementing this.

I have been used this code.

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
 if(self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
 {
     // initialize my object.
 }
 return self;
}
```

But I have to make same code for UIView instantiated by code like this.

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
 if(self=[super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
 {
     // initialize my object.
 }
 return self;
}
- (id) initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
 if(self=[super initWithFrame:frame])
 {
     // initialie my obejct.
 }
 return self;
}
```

I feels something wrong. Any recommendations?

*Of source the initialization logic can be extracted into a new method, but it's not a point.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. What I gave you was the standard pattern for initializing a UIView when you want to either load the view from a NIB or initialize it programmatically. If you're only loading it from a NIB, just implement awakeFromNib. You shouldn't implement initWithCoder for a UIView. There aren't any guarantees about what order it will be called in and what state the rest of the objects will be in when initWithCoder gets called.

Comment: @Jacques Thanks. Your mentioning a lot helpful to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use awakeFromNib to initialize a UIView that's being created from a NIB file. If you want to make it general so that it can be created either from a NIB file or programmatically, make a method like configureObject and call it from both the designated initializer (often initWithFrame:) and from awakeFromNib.

```
- (void)configureObject {
    // Do initialization here
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])
    {
        [self configureObject];
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [self configureObject];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from Jacques answer, which is the correct way to solve this problem, you had a logic error. In your `initWithCoder` you have set `self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];` and then you do `return [self init];`. In `init`, you again overwrite self through `self = [super init];`, potentially reversing things you have done in `initWithCoder:`. And again in `init`, you have `return [self init];` which causes an endless recursion until the stack overflows.

The pattern for init methods is something like this:

```
- (id) initWithFoo:(Bar *)baz {
    if ((self = [super initWithFoo:baz])) {
        // Do custom initialization.
    }

    return self;
}
```

or:

```
- (id) initWithFoo:(Bar *)baz {
    if ((self = [super initWithSome:baz other:@"signature"])) {
        // Do custom initialization.
    }

    return self;
}
```

Also, a bit of clarification: `- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder` gets called on deserialization. In this case on deserialization done by loading a NIB/XIB. There is a counterpart, `- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`. Read the [Archives and Serialization Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html), you might find that useful if you want to store objects on disk or want to transmit them over a network.

Anyway, with NIBs, once they are loaded the `awakeFromNib` method is called for each object that is stored inside a NIB and it serves as a kind of second-level-initializer.

Then, there's `initWithFrame:`. This is the designated initializer and the one you call when creating UIView instances programmatically.

Comment: Oh sorry. It was my mistake not to check sample code. I updated my question :)